# virtualenv does not copy standard modules like shutil and urllib2

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I create a new virtualenv, `virtualenv .virtualenvs/my_env`, there is only a subset of the standard python modules copied/linked to the new virtualenv.

For example, when I do `ls -l` in .virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.6, I see:

```
...
... os.py -> /usr/lib/python2.6/os.py
... os.pyc -> /usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc
```

but modules like `shutil` and `urllib2` are not copied even if they are in `/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py`. I am using Ubuntu 9.10.

Is this the expected behavior? How can I install modules such as shutil in a virtualenv (I could not find these modules on pypi)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

virtualenv munges `sys.path` to insert your virtual environment *in front* of the system libraries, but the system libraries are still on the path, so they should still be accessible.

So, for instance, do:

```
>>> import os
>>> os
<module 'posixpath' from '/environments/userpython/lib/python2.6/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil
<module 'shutil' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/shutil.pyc'>
```

My os module is from my virtual environment, but the shutil module is coming from my system Python.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This explains the behavior I observed.

For pydev users, don't forget to add the python system path when adding a virtualenv interpreter.

Comment: Any idea why some modules are being copied/symlinked but others do not?

Comment: I'm interested in this too. For bundling cases like `dh_virtualenv`, you really do want total isolation, especially if your venv's python is not the same version as the default on the target system.